# How to compare two pdf documents using Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache, pdf, apache-tika

I want to compare two pdf documents (not only contents but also other information such as header footers and styles).

I got to know that we can use Apache tika for comparison purpose. I have learnt to parse the pdf document and able to extract some metadata info such as title, author.

I'm right now able to do like this -

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;

import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class CompareDocs {
    public CompareDocs() {
        super();
    }

    private void parseResource(String resourceName) {  
            System.out.println("Parsing resource : " + resourceName);  
            InputStream inputStream = null;  

            try {  
                try {
                        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(resourceName)));   
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();  
                ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();  
                Metadata metadata = new Metadata();  

                parser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());  

                for (String name : metadata.names()) {  
                    String value = metadata.get(name);  
                    System.out.println("Metadata Name: " + name);  
                    System.out.println("Metadata Value: " + value);  
                }  

                System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get("title"));  
                System.out.println("Author: " + metadata.get("Author"));  
                System.out.println("content: " + contentHandler.toString());  

            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (TikaException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (SAXException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } finally {  
                if (inputStream != null) {  
                    try {  
                        inputStream.close();  
                    } catch (IOException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompareDocs apacheTikaParser = new CompareDocs();  
               apacheTikaParser.parseResource("C:\\Users\\prakhar\\Desktop\\beautiful_code.pdf");  
    }
}
```

How can we extract some more information such as header distance of first section, image height and width etc and compare these with another pdf using Apache Tika.

Answer (score 7):

[Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) detects and extracts metadata and structured text content. It doesn't support to find header distance of first section, image height and width  etc.

You can try [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) or [Itext](http://itextpdf.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm also curious as docx files have style, header, footer infor in corresponding xml's. The pdf file takes care of these things or it take care of these things, whether we can extract these details or not. After looking at the Tika generated structured data representation it seems that it is not having any information like this? Please answer.

Comment: Tika only extract Text content not styles.

Comment: Okay, this leads me to ask whether we can get information such as font size, name, color etc for the text in the pdf using Tika?

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to more information, maybe it is more convenient to use another api like [PDFTextStream](http://snowtide.com/). Tika extracts raw textual information from a pdf, while [PDFTextStream](http://snowtide.com/) gives you structured text with correlated info such as character encoding, height, region of the text etc.